# What is my error in the very simple php?

Tags: php, if-statement

i make a very simple php to check a data, but it not works.

```
<?php
    $ngl="G";
    if ($parsed[0][4]="0") {
        $ngl="NG";
    }
    if ($parsed[0][5]="0") {
        $ngl="NG";
    }
?>
```

and the output of the

```
<?php echo $ngl; ?>
```

is always

```
G
```

But I know that `$parsed[0][4]` and `$parsed[0][5]` is `0`. The problem is that the output is `G` and not `NG`! I also tried to remove `$ngl="G";` but then the output is nothing.

What do I have to repair?

i just use = but == its the correct. thx all.

Comment: You're confusing the assignment operator `=` with the equality operator `==`

Comment: Try with double `==` like `if ($parsed[0][4] == "0") {`

Comment: Hm... wondering who's going to win this one ;-)

Comment: @Fred well, I was first, so in my experience, not me :P

Comment: Both if statements lead to the same result `$ngl = "NG";`. I don't quite understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: I think this question is going for a world record - most answers given that are exactly the same

Comment: @Fred "Win" this one? Hopefully the user requesting assistance. Speed to answer is no longer a factor in gaining reputation since answers are often edited to duplicate other answers. Clear example will be shown in a few minutes when every one of these answers will contain nearly identical information, links and code examples.

Comment: @Vector It's a "Lottery", anyone can win ;-) However, the important thing is to provide a "solution". Rep points are nice, yet not being downvoted is proof in itself, cheers. (*Peace*)

Comment: @DevlshOne You'll eventually "get to know me" ;-)  In all seriousness, it's all about finding/giving a "solution" in the end, Cheers. (*Peace*)

Comment: Ladies & Gentlemen, [**We have a Winner**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18190514/1415724) (Today's prize: A good feeling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning (`=`) a value instead of comparing (`==` or `===`)

```
<?php
$ngl = "G";
if($parsed[0][4] == "0")
{
    $ngl = "NG";
}
if($parsed[0][5] == "0")
{
    $ngl = "NG";
}
?>
```

**Explanation:**

When you put an assignment like `$parsed[0][4]="0"` in an if statement, the `if` will evaluate the "0" to `false`. The reason it evaluates just the "0" is because the line `$parsed[0][4]="0"` (any assignment) returns the right hand side of the operation (the "0")

`==` **vs** `===` **:** [php.net - Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

`==` is a loose comparison which doesn't compare the type. ie `"2" == 2` is `true` (even though one is a string and the other is an integer)

`===` is a strict comparison, comparing types as well as values. ie `"2" === 2` is `false`

The if statement uses the former (loose) comparison on your "0", and of course 0 is the false value in binary (0 and 1), so `0 == false` and `"0" == false` both evaluate to true - however, `0 === false` would return false as `0` is an integer, whereas `false` is a boolean.

Comment: +1 for mentioned the `===` operator, and why the evaluation is failing. Could you also add something explaining the difference between `==` and `===`?

Comment: And what happens if I use `====`, `&&` or `||` ? Could you explain truth tables and how all those operators affect this snippet of code? Where are the "official" explanations for all these operators?

Comment: @DevlshOne They aren't relevant here

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` not `=` when checking

```
<?php
$ngl="G";
if ($parsed[0][4]=="0") {
$ngl="NG";
}
if ($parsed[0][5]=="0") {
$ngl="NG";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `=` to set variables. You use `==` to compare.

```
<?php
    $ngl="G";
    if ($parsed[0][4]=="0") {
        $ngl="NG";
    }
    if ($parsed[0][5]=="0") {
        $ngl="NG";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` rather than `=`:

```
<?php
    $ngl="G";
    if ($parsed[0][4]=="0") {
        $ngl="NG";
    }
    if ($parsed[0][5]=="0") {
        $ngl="NG";
    }
?>
```

The reason is that the `=` is the assignment operator, while the `==` is the comparison operator (which is the one you want).

`$parsed[0][4]=="0"` will evaluate to `0`, which is false, so `$ngl` will not be changed.  The same thing happens with `$parsed[0][5]=="0"`

Answer (score 0):

This line is not checking if $parsed[0][4] is zero. It makes it zero.

```
if ($parsed[0][4]="0") {
```

Change it to

```
if ($parsed[0][4]=="0") {
```